# Data extraction from a SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2013, lambda

I need some help with an extraction method. I am currently working on a school card project and I need to extract all students learning in certain teachers class. I have table named `Teachers`, table named `Classes` and a table named `Students`. I want by given `Teacher ID` to receive all the students in his/her class.

- Table `Teachers` contains `TeacherID, Name, and so on`.
- `Classes` contains `TeacherID, StudentID`.
- `Students` contains `StudentID and FirstName, LastName`.

My problem is that I want to return a whole list of students and I am not quite sure how to do it and what type I should be using. Could you please assist me ?

The code so far

```
var studentID = from t in context.Teachers 
                join s in context.Classes on t.TeacherID equals s.TeacherID
                join stu in context.Students on s.StudentID equals stu.StudentID
                select stu.FirstName
                .SelectMany();
```

As you can see the use of `.SelectMany()` is wrong and thus I do not seem to be able to replace it with anything so far. Also, since there are many names the use of var is incorrect, I suppose.

Comment: post your code as part of your original question not in the comments...

Comment: are you familiar with the `Select new {  };` construct? also I would think that you would want to use `.ToList()` then use a `foreach()` to iterate across the collection..

Answer (score 0):

how about this..

```
var studentID = from t in context.Teachers 
                join s in context.Classes on t.TeacherID equals s.TeacherID
                join stu in context.Students on s.StudentID equals stu.StudentID
                WHERE stu.FirstName == FirstName
                select t;
```

`I would do it on something more unique what if you have 5 Thomas's ?`

Comment: if you want a particular Students name you would need to place in a `WHERE` Clause.

Comment: What would be the behavior if there are many student names ? Wouldn't it cause problem ? There is no need, really ..

Comment: look at my comment...I will update to show an example

Comment: you can do this without a `Where` Clause and then implement the `foreach(var item in studentId)` loop many ways to skin this cat..